# pyCharm: How to export settings which differ from default

Tags: version-control, settings, pycharm

How can I export the settings of pyCharm which differ from the default value?

In other words: only the settings which were changed by me?

Background: I want to build a base setting for our company, which I want to store in version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible in general. PyCharm does not track which settings have been changed compared to the defaults.

Note that for some specific settings (for example, code style or inspections), PyCharm does support storing the settings as a scheme which can easily be shared within a team or a company.